# No se muestra ícono en boton Materialize

Tags: php, css, materialize

Estoy tratando de mostrar un botón el cual tiene un ícono.
Quiero mostrar algo como:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn indigo m-b-xs"><i class="material-icons left">cloud</i>Indigo</a>
```

El caso es que cuando hago una consulta a la base de datos y mostrar los datos con un for each solo me sale el ícono pero no se muestra el texto que debe de ir dentro del botón.

Código HTML.

```html
   <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <table class="display responsive-table datatable-example dataTable">
           <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Campo1</th>
              <th>Campo2</th>
              <th>Campo3</th>
              <th>Detalles</th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <?php foreach ($proyecto as $value) { ?>
              <tr>
               <td><?= $value["id"] ?></td>
               <td><?= $value["campo1"] ?></td>
               <td><?= $value["campo2"] ?></td>
               <td><?= $value["campo3"] ?></td>
               <td>
                 <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn indigo m-b-xs"><i class="material-icons left">cloud</i>Indigo</a>
               </td>
              </tr>
             <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
           </table>
```

Agradecería su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: A mi si que me aparece :/

Comment: El botón se ve igual en ambos ejemplos, se ven bien tanto el icono de la nube como el texto (INDIGO).

Comment: Realmente no se que sucede, por alguna razón solo se muestra el ícono (cloud) cuando realizo la consulta y la muestro en la tabla con un for each